# Asynchronously load Image in Enyo

Tags: enyo

I have a enyo.List with two items: an enyo.Image and a text component. I setSrc on the Image during onSetupItem.

This loads the image immediately , since I have over 10 rows they don't appear till all the images load. Is there anyway to load these images asynchronously (additionally display the image with a "fade-in" animation ?). Thanks.

Comment: enyo Images should load asynchronously; if what you're describing is accurate, it may be a bug. What happens if you use `{tag: 'img' ...}` instead?

Comment: A jsfiddle would help as well when describing these issues.

Comment: I was going to say the same thing(s) as Travis.  You can look at the sampler to see how images are loaded for the Flickr sample.  http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/enyo/nightly/dependencies/onyx,layout,canvas,g11n/  img tag may work better if you don't use the image events.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Totally wrote this next paragraph backwards.  List -is- the flyweight version.  You were correct to set the number of rows.

What you may want to do is to replace the `List` with a `Repeater`.  Because of the flyweight pattern in the `Repeater` you might not be requesting as many images at once.

Another approach might be to derive a new kind based on a `Scroller` that detects when images scroll into view and only load them at that time. That is a pretty involved approach and you might need to create a kind based of `Image` that works hand-in-hand with the other kind.

You could also Google some lazy-loading strategies and see if you can apply those.

Comment: Thanks. I found that setting rowsPerPage on enyo.List to a lower number made the enyo.List request only a small subset from the data array.